# How to call stored procedure using sqlalchemy

Tags: python, mysql, google-app-engine, sqlalchemy

How can I call stored procedures of MySQL with sqlAlchemy?

I tried the following code:

```
import webapp2

from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import create_session
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

class TestSQL(webapp2.RequestHandler):

def get(self):
    Base = automap_base()

    engine = create_engine(('mysql://root@127.0.0.1:3306/testDB?unix_socket=/cloudsql/School=:mysqlserver'))
    # reflect the tables
    Base.prepare(engine, reflect=True)

    metadata = MetaData(bind=engine)
    users = Table('Student', metadata, autoload=True)
    student = metadata.tables ["Student"]

    session = create_session()

    pro = session.execute("p_get_teacher_requests", (1,0))
    self.response.write(pro)
```

Here the error that I got:

```
UnboundExecutionError: Could not locate a bind configured on SQL expression or this Session
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After some research, and many trails it worked with the following code:

```
import webapp2

from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import create_session
from sqlalchemy import create_engine


class TestSQL(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"

        Base = automap_base()

        engine = create_engine(('mysql://root@IP:3306/School?unix_socket=/cloudsql/school:mysqlserver'))

        # reflect the tables
        Base.prepare(engine, reflect=True)

        metadata = MetaData(bind=engine)

        users = Table('Student', metadata, autoload=True)
        student = metadata.tables ["Student"]

        session = create_session()

        connection = engine.raw_connection()
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.callproc("p_get_teacher_requests", [1,0])
        results = list(cursor.fetchall())
        cursor.close()
        connection.commit()

        self.response.write(results)
```

Comment: This is a life saver answer! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Great. cursor.callproc works. session.execute, session.execute(func.. ) did not work with mysql. Thanks!

Comment: For future readers, it's good practice to make sure the connection is always closed, even in the event of an Exception being raised. Do this by wrapping your code in the `try` statement and use `finally: connection.close()`